# Rar is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, compression, winrar

I installed [winrar](/questions/tagged/winrar) in `D:\folderD`, both at home, and at work. I have a `.rar` file in drive `E:`, `E:\folderE\myfile.rar`. So, at home I can successfully use the Windows Command Prompt in drive `H:` with the following command:

```
H:\>unrar x E:\folderE\myfile.rar C:\folderC
```

The problem appears in my computer at work.

If I do at work the same operation I did above, I receive the error message:

> 'rar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I then tried at work to copy just the `Rar.exe` and the `Unrar.exe` from the installation folder `D:\folderD`, and paste them into `C:\Windows\System32`. I still get the error.

What should I do to fix this to every machine at work, since `winrar` could have been installed in different folders in other departments?

I did another test. Installed winrar in the root of folder `c:\windows\system32`. Apparently, when repeating the command `H:>unrar x E:\folderE\myfile.rar C:\folderC` the operation run normally. Yet, when I switched off the computer and came back hours latter, I repeated the latter command and again the error "Rar is not recognized as an internal or external command". If I go to `c:\windows\system32` and use DOS prompt to search for `rar*.exe` or `unrar*.exe`, nothing is found, but **those files are there. I can see them with windows explorer!** They are not with the hidden attribute. The winrar I am using is for 64bit and the system is Windows 10, 64 bit.

`F:\>dir C:\Windows\System32\WinRAR.exe`
`C:\>dir C:\Windows\System32\*rar*.exe`

> File WinRAR.exe not found 
> File not found

What is going on? Heeelllpp ....

Comment: Winrar and it's command-line programs are typically installed to `C:\Program Files\WinRAR` and not added to the PATH (nowadays programs never ever should install them to `C:\Windows\...`). If you want to execute them you have to execute them with full path like `C:\Program Files\WinRAR\unrar` or add the folder to your user/system PATH variable.

Comment: What is happening SPECIFICALLY is that you are not allowed to install programs in system32.  People that would do this are a tech support nightmare.  I am assuming that you are experiencing UAC Folder Virtualization.  Windows "lets" you do this.. but actually puts the files somewhere else.  Rather than fight this behavior, see @Wasif_Hasan answer for the right way.  Also.. WHY RAR?  WHY A PAID PROGRAM when SO MANY are free?  See 7zip.

Comment: @Robert Even executing it with full path I get the same error. The simple verification of going directly to the source of the installation and typing on the prompt `C:\Windows\System32\rar /?`, we get that 'rar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. The file is there. I can double click on rar.exe or unrar.exe or winrar.exe by using the windows explorer and it opens each of the three executables.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you for your post, but when I say "at Work", I also say that there "at work" my friends, who are the owners and adm. of their laptops have the same problem as well. However, at home I do not have problems at all with my own personal computer. I have never tried to bring my personal computer to work and make a test there. But I have just realised that the command PATH gives in my personal computer the following DOS prompt result: `c:\Windows\system32;c:\WINDOWS\system32;c:\Windows;c:\WINDOWS`. Do you think that capital letters makes all this difference?

Comment: No, windows paths are not case sensitive. Try looking in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore` on a machine where it isn't working.  I am guessing that you will find your answer there.

Comment: Also..it doesn't matter that you are an admin or not.  UAC affects admins and non-admins alike.  Do you not get a popup from an installer or running regedit?  It also mananges the very problem you are dealing with so that Win95-WinVista programs don't break because of permissions.  Technically, you can change the permissions on System32 but DO NOT.  This will only result in people (rightfully) hating you for bad choices

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parent folder path of Rar.exe or UnRar.exe to the PATH environment variable to execute them without specifying the full path in Command Prompt.

To add a file/folder path to the PATH environment variable, use the command `setx PATH "%PATH%;The path to be added"` Where `The path to be added` is the parent folder of filepath, and then close and start Command Prompt again.

To list the directories in PATH, you can use:

```
powershell -nop -c $env:PATH-split';'
```

Comment: Thank you, but before comming to the forum I certified that the path where the Winrar is installed was already a part of the environment. As I mentioned, I have installed all the Winrar files directly in `c:\windows\system32` root (no extra folders). If I use the msdos prompt with the command `c:\path` + ENTER, I get some software paths separated by a semicolon `;` , where one of those path is `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;`. Therefore, the path is already there.

Comment: What happens if you type `where rar` at the command prompt?

Comment: @ldnamdd I would assume that the installer of WinRAR is a 32 bit program. Therefore you have not installed WinRAR to the System32 folder but into the WoW64 branch. In any way installing any software into Windows folder is strictly prohibited unless you like dozens of problems and the fact that all the installed software will disappear with the next Windows upgrade in next spring.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In fact I discovered that I have two scenarios. The first, I open DOS and the rar.exe is there. No matter what drive I go, if I type `where rar` the system shows me `C:\Windows\System32\Rar.exe`. So far, so good. The problem appears while I am accessing my batch with the command in Delphi: `ShellExecute(Application.handle, 'open', 'cmd.exe', PChar('/K "c:\myfolder\my.bat"'), nil, SW_SHOW);` A new DOS window appears and presents the error spoken in this post title. Then, if I use in this newly open DOS prompt `where rar`, I get "info: not possible to locate files specified"

Comment: @Wasif Hasan, I updated my comment. I wrote a Delphi app and at some point it calls a batch.This batch executes the rar.exe and, when it does, a DOS windows prompts with the error "rar is not recognized as an internal ...". If I use this DOS prompt to try and find out about my rar.exe whereabouts, it does not find any rar at all! If I insist and use windows explorer, I see the rar.exe. I tried calling from Delphi a series of intermediate batch that calls other batches that, then, calls my real batch, but no matter how many secondary batches I make, the final result is the same error.

Comment: @ldnamdd Why not use UnRar Delphi component?